# Azure Static Web App - Application Settings using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Using Terraform, I created an Azure Static Web App as below. But the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/static_site)  does not demonstrate how to set application settings for the resource. For normal Azure functions apps we can see [app_settings](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#app_settings) parameter. But how to set app settings for azure static web app created using Terraform?

```hcl
resource "azurerm_static_site" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = "example"
  location            = "West Europe"
}
```

I like to set parameters `AAD_CLIENT_ID` and `AAD_CLIENT_SECRET` to configure identity provider for the azure static web app as in microsoft [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad#configure-a-custom-identity-provider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to configure application setting as of the time of this writing. For example:

```
resource "azurerm_static_site" "my_static_frontend" {
  name                = "my_cool_app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  app_settings = {
    "DB_CONNECTION_STRING"      = local.db_conn_string
    "STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING" = azurerm_storage_account.mystorageacct.secondary_connection_string
    "AZURE_CLIENT_ID"           = azuread_application_registration.my_static_frontend.client_id
    "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"       = azuread_application_password.my_static_frontend.value
  }
}
```

Comment: Provider minimum version: [3.76.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases/tag/v3.76.0).

Answer (score 5):

**Original Answer:** Application settings on Azure static web apps is an open [feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/13451) as of now (24/Nov/2021). I will update this answer as the feature is added to Terraform.

**UPDATE:** With AzAPI Terraform provider [[2](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi)], we could manage resources not *presently* supported by AzureRM provider. Code sample below for application settings and Azure function linkage to static web app.

```
# For AzAPI provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
      version = "~> 1.0"
    }
  }
}

# For static web app 
resource azurerm_static_site swa {
  name                = "myswa"
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
  location            = "westeurope"

  # ignore below if you do not need to link functions
  sku_tier            = "Standard"
  sku_size            = "Standard"
}

# For application settings. You may change to azapi_resource once Github issue 
# https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi/issues/256 is closed.
resource azapi_resource_action appsetting {
  type = "Microsoft.Web/staticSites/config@2022-03-01"
  resource_id = "${azurerm_static_site.swa.id}/config/appsettings"
  method = "PUT"

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
        "mykey"="myvalue"
    }
  })
}

# For linking Azure function. Ignore if not needed
resource azapi_resource linktofunction {
  type = "Microsoft.Web/staticSites/userProvidedFunctionApps@2022-03-01"
  name = "swalinktofunction"
  parent_id = azurerm_static_site.swa.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      functionAppRegion = "westeurope"
      # below swafunction created else where
      functionAppResourceId = azurerm_windows_function_app.swafunction.id
    }
  })
}
```

For application settings, I was forced to use `azapi_resource_action` since `azapi_resource` was not working for issue [[3](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi/issues/256)]. This has an important consequence: *if application settings is deleted or updated via external means like Azure portal or az cli, Terraform will not know about it*. This is not ideal, but that is best we could get with Terraform for now.

Comment: Worth to mention that now there is a workaround provided under this feature request.

Answer (score 1):

For this effect, and for the sake of simplicity and keeping the terraform code clean, I prefer to use `az cli`:

```
az staticwebapp appsettings set --name my_webapp_name --setting-names "SETTING_NAME=setting_value" --subscription "$(my_subscription_id)"
```

This can also be automated and, just as any IaC tool, is idempotent. Thus on my Azure DevOps pipeline, I'm applying these settings after running terraform.

Comment: +1. Agree. I would prefer this over `azapi_resource_action`. I am not marking as answer, only since, original question title requested solution using Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky with following AzureRM + AzApi configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_static_site" "example_app" {
  name                = "example-app"
  resource_group_name = "example-rg"
  location            = "West Europe"
}

resource "azapi_update_resource" "example_app_settings" {
  type = "Microsoft.Web/staticSites@2022-03-01"
  resource_id = azurerm_static_site.example_app.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      customDomains = [
        "www.example.com"
      ]
      repositoryUrl = "https://github.com/example"
      branch = "example"
    }
  })
}
```

to see all available properties and their format, go to your Static Web App and in the Overview open the JSON View on the right side.

It might be a better idea to create and configure the Static Web App with AzAPI only instead of creating and updating with different providers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/templates/microsoft.web/staticsites?pivots=deployment-language-terraform

Comment: Did you not face this issue https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi/issues/256 ?